Has the result returned by the getScores method of EdgeBetweennessCentricity been normalized
As shown in the following code, has the result returned by edgeEdgeBetweennessCentricity. getScores() been normalized?
private <V,E> Map<E, Double> calculateEdgeBetweenness(Graph<V, E> graph) {

        EdgeBetweennessCentrality<V, E> edgeEdgeBetweennessCentrality = new EdgeBetweennessCentrality<>(graph);
        Map<E, Double> scores = edgeEdgeBetweennessCentrality.getScores();

        return scores;
    }

has the result returned by edgeEdgeBetweennessCentricity. getScores() been normalized? If not, how should normalization be handled？
